# How can I create undefined number of TextInput and take their value on kivy with python code?

Tags: python, kivy

Hi I want to create n TextInput widget and take theirs value with only python if it’s possible. I’m using kivy This is my python code:

```
class S(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, *kwargs):
        super().__init__(*kwargs)
        self.cols=2
        For i in range(n):
            self.t=TextInput()
            self.add_widget(self.t)
```

I want to take the value of each self.t
And another question by the way, how can I import a value from another python file ? (From name.file import value doesn’t work)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a list of the `TextInput` widgets, like this:

```
class S(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, *kwargs):
        super().__init__(*kwargs)
        self.cols=2
        self.tis = []
        For i in range(n):
            self.t=TextInput()
            self.add_widget(self.t)
            self.tis.append(self.t)
```

Comment: Thanks that works well when I use it in my main screen, but the probleme is when I use it in another py file (I'm using multiple screen), so the list self.tis is empty when the screen is created and it remains empty even if the user enter some data.